# Reading delimited txt file into JTable

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable, csv

I went through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Myhn_m-Bzgc) to learn how to use Netbeans to create a GUI application to take information in on a form, be able to edit it, and save it to a JTable. I now want to expand what I learned to be able to write this JTable to a delimited text file and read it in at a later date to add more data.  I have managed to successfully write the data to a file.  The code for that is here and is executed through a menu event I created:

```
private void mnuSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        try {

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            for (int i = 0; i < tblProduct.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < tblProduct.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    bw.write((String) tblProduct.getModel().getValueAt(i, j) + "#");
                }
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.close();
            fw.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("problem accessing file" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}
```

I have read many posts dealing with things such as StringTokenizer but I just can't seem to wrap my head around what approach to take.  Any direction would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

@camickr: Wasn't working at first but I figured it out.  I wasn't adding a "\n" when writing the file.  I have updated my code and also added code to clear my Jtable when opening a new file.  Let me know if there's anything that is not "good practice".

```
private void mnuOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String line;
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblProduct.getModel();

    for (int i = tblProduct.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        model.removeRow(i);
    }

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                model.addRow(line.split("#"));
            }

            br.close();
            fr.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("problem accessing file" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}
```

Here is what my test textfile looks like as generated:

```
Test1#Electronic#23.50#
Test2#Art#100.00#
Test3#Food#25.00#
Test4#Electronic#10.00#
Test5#Art#1.00#
Test6#Electricity#3.00#
Test7#Food#5.00#
Test8#Food#7.00#
Test9#Electronic#9.00#
```

Comment: *"wasn't adding a "\n" when writing the file"* See [`BufferedWriter.newLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--) for a more robust approach.

Comment: Could you please share how does your text file look like?

Comment: @Sanjeev Saha: I have edited my OP to include my test textfile listing

Comment: So @john8791 are you successful in displaying your text file in a `JTable`?

Comment: @Sanjeev Saha: Yes, everything works now.

Comment: Nice! Actually I thought of solution of setting a new model on the `JTable` each time you read a new file instead of adding and removing row from the existing model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an empty DefaultTableModel with your column names.
2. Then you can use the `String.split(...)` method to split each line of data.
3. Then you can use the `addRow(...)` method of the DefaultTableModel to add the data to the model.
4. Then can create your JTable with the DefaultTableModel.